# How to read the results in this case?

Tags: econometrics, stata

From running the code for testing parallel trends, I perform the code below following the suggestion of [xtdidregression guideline, page 15.](https://www.stata.com/manuals/tedidregress.pdf)

```
estat ptrends
```

And I got the results below

```
Parallel-trends test (pretreatment    time    period)
H0: Linear trends are parallel

F(1, 441) =   0.73
Prob > F = 0.3935
```

In this case, I wonder whether the parallel trend assumption is satisfied. From my point of view, it seems that the parallel trend assumption is not violated in this case due to that the Prob>F (or p-value) >0.1
From my point of view, Prob>F <0.05 is to reject the parallel trend assumption. So how should we conclude in this case.